# Unicode in Python

Tags: python, unicode

In Python 2.7's documentation, three rules about Unicode are described as follows:

> If the code point is <128, it’s represented by the corresponding byte value.
>
> If the code point is between 128 and `0x7ff`, it’s turned into two byte values between 128 and 255.
>
> Code points >`0x7ff` are turned into three- or four-byte sequences, where each byte of the sequence is between 128 and 255.

Then I made some tests about it:

```
>>>> unichr(40960)

u'\ua000'

>>> ord(u'\ua000')

40960
```

In my view, 40960 is a code point > `0x7ff`, so it should be turned into three- or four-byte sequences, where each byte of the sequence is between 128 and 255, but it only be turned into two-bytes sequence, and the value '00' in u'\a000' is lower than 128, not matched with the rules mentioned above. Why?

What's more, I found some more Unicode characters, such as `u'\u1234'`, etc. I found that the value ("12" && "34") in it is also lower than 128, but according to the thoery mentioned first, they shouldn't be lower than 128. Any other theories that I lost?

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> in python2.7's documentation, three rules about unicodes are described as follows:

That is a description of the UTF-8 encoding.

> Then I made some tests about it:

`\ua000` is an escape sequence representing a Unicode character. The `a000` is a hexadecimal representation of the numerical code point value. It **has nothing to do with** UTF-8 encoding.

You get UTF-8 encoding when you explicitly encode a unicode string using the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Correct. `\ua000` is an escaped hex encoding, not the byte representation in UTF-8. The poster needs to review UTF-8 encodings.

Comment: Thanks, I consult some documentations about UTF-8 && Unicode, and finally know the relations between them.

Answer (score 3):

Your quote apparently comes from [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) (you really should have told us where it came from, with a link if possible) and describes UTF-8.  It does not claim that this is how Python 2.7 represents Unicode characters, in fact it does the opposite:

> Under the hood, Python represents Unicode strings as either 16- or 32-bit integers, depending on how the Python interpreter was compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Those rules only apply for UTF-8. Python uses UCS-2 or UCS-4 internally, which have fixed sizes.

["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

> ... and the value '00' in u'\a000' is lower than 128, not matched with the rules mentioned above.

I don't even want to **know** why you think they can be split up like this...

Comment: The internal representation isn't actually relevant to the question. The point is that UTF-8 encoding is not reflected in the syntax for Unicode string literals.

Comment: @Karl: Fair enough. But the article is still relevant (and what I said is still true regardless of its relevance).