# Why when i am getting u'' in front of column names when reading csv file in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have a csv file in my local and i am reading that csv in using pd.read_csv()

Csv kinda looks like this say name df.csv

```
 # a     b       c
--------------------
"SS" |  1   |  Null
"GG" |  1   |  "lk"
"HH" |  2   |  "kk"
```

But when i am read this file in python

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r"path/df.csv")
print(df1.columns)
```

out_put:

```
Index([u'# a', u' b', u' c', ],dtype='object')
```

Comment: the u-string means that the string is in unicode.

Comment: for your ref: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808657/what-is-a-unicode-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808657/what-is-a-unicode-string)